# Is it posible to multiple entry value before submit Gravity forms?

Tags: customization, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

Is there any way to do this case in Gravity forms:

I use:

- Gravity Forms
- Gravity Forms Multi Pages

I have three steps:

- Step 1: contain Option Field
- Step 2: also contains the option Field
- Step 3: This is step contain option (Add New and Proceed)
- Step 4: Form that COntains user information that the user need to field before submitting

Is it possible to make it after Step 1 & Step 2 are selected, and in Step 3 if the user selects Add New it will back to Step 1, but the previous answer from Step 1 that user chooses before selecting Add new,  will save and submitted to the entry along with new answer?

And if the user has 2 new data for each field in steps 1 & step 2 will be submitted in one entry?